# What are the parts of speech and grammatical roles in the sentence “I don’t know very much”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles

In the sentence:

> I don't know very much.

What parts of speech do the words *know very much* play?

*I* is clearly the subject, and *don’t* is a verb/adverb contraction.

Is *know* an adverb to *do*?

*Very* seems like an adjective, but then what is *much*?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking here: what's a "role of speech"? Do you mean a [part of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) or a [grammatical role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_relation)?

Comment: I have changed my post to use 'part' consistantly. I was not aware that the word 'role' would be confusing, I definitely meant 'part of speech'.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know very much.*

"I" is a pronoun  functioning as 'subject'.

"don't" is a verb (auxiliary) functioning as 'predicator'.

"know" is a verb functioning as 'predicator'.

"very" is an adverb function as 'modifier'.

"much" is a determinative functioning as 'determiner-head'.

Note: function = grammatical role.

Answer (score -1):

*I* is the subject, *don’t know* is the verb, and *very much* is the direct object. The verb and direct object together make up the predicate.

1. *I* is the first-person-singular **personal pronoun** in the subject case.
2. *Don’t* is **negated auxiliary verb**, the first part of a multiword verb phrase. It is not marked as a third-person-singular because the subject is in the first person.
3. *Know* is the **bare infinitive verb**, the second part of a multiword verb phrase.
4. *Very* is here best considered an **intensifier**, not a general-purpose adverb: notice how it cannot modify verbs. Some analyses treat it as an adjective (*the very idea!*) or an adverb, but I prefer intensifier.
5. *Much* can in general be an **adverb** (*much better*), a **determinative** / **determiner** (*much trouble*), or a **pronoun** (*didn’t each much*) especially when used with negated verbs as a sort of ***negative polarity item*** (NPI).  The last seems to fit best here.